# what are the options for the psql \copy command?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I was looking at the [psql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html):

> \copy { table [ ( column_list ) ] | ( query ) } { from | to } {
>   'filename' | program 'command' | stdin | stdout | pstdin | pstdout } [
>   [ with ] ( option [, ...] ) ]

but couldn't quite figure out what are the possible options in the last `with` clause. Looking at `\? \copy` in psql doesn't give much information either. Any pointers to what are these options?

The only one I know so far is `with csv`. I have a space separated file, which I don't know how to `\copy` into postgres via psql.

Comment: From the manual: "*All options other than the data source/destination are as specified for [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)*"